# Cannot create hive table in cloudera quickstartVM

Tags: hive, cloudera, sqoop

I'm trying to create tables in hive in cloudera quickstartvm 5.5, but it says "Logging intializing" and takes long time, even after long time it doesn't create tables in hive, also cannot import tables to hive.. I have seen lot of questions in stackoverflow on the same issue, but can't find answer. If someone know or got answer for this please share the info. Thanks in advance..

Comment: I used vmware player, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below from Cloudera community blog

*After restarting Hive Service, I tried creating table using Hue worked.. After that create tables in hive started working.. Not sure about the magic behind..*

I was new to Cloudera VM and did the following steps. Stopped Hue followed by Hive and started Hive & Hue. One extra thing which I did is to follow the quick start steps in Hue which installed couple of sample tables/databases in Hive. Hope this helps for others who are new to Cloudera VM and facing the same issue.

Comment: Please don't post identical answers to multiple questions. Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question.*